# Web.config Transformation Syntax for appSettings file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to change my web.config appSetting file's name:

With the rule:

```
<appSettings file="ExternalAppSettings.Release.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(file)"/>
```

But this is not working, what am I missing/doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. That file was missing on the publish.

On the file: "ExternalAppSettings.Release.config" I needed to change the properties: Copy to Output Directory > Copy Always.

Comment: I've had that problem before.